# Spring Cloud Discovery Server for kubernetes integration with Feign Client or RestTemplate

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have used spring cloud discovery server for kubernetes based on this release notes.

https://spring.io/blog/2021/10/26/new-features-for-spring-cloud-kubernetes-in-spring-cloud-2021-0-0-m3

A GET request sent to http://localhost/apps is also returning JSON array of available services as expected.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/2.1.0-M3/reference/html/#apps

My question is how do I configure Feign Client or RestTemplate to consume the endpoint services provided by the Discovery Server.

(Feign Client or RestTemplate) does not seems to resolve the service names.

Comment: Have you included spring cloud load balancer as a dependency?

Comment: @spencergibb it worked after adding spring cloud load balancer as a dependency.